# Enabling iCloud with Provisioning Profiles in my App

Tags: ios, icloud, provisioning-profile

**I'm extremely new to iCloud development** and while *I have 2 versions of my app out in the app store*, it's time to bring iCloud functionality.

There are a few questions that I need to ask. These may seem really basic, but I need to understand the right procedures before continuing and I can't seem to find this information anywhere online.

My app only supports iOS 7 and I'm using the latest Xcode as well.

**Question and Uncertainty**

> All of the tutorials I've seen cover implementing iCloud into a new
>   app rather than an app that already exists in the App Store and which
>   already has an App ID and provisioning profiles. Do I have to create a
>   new App ID or can I just edit my existing App ID to include iCloud and
>   then generate new provisioning profiles?
>
> Also, if I generate new provisioning profiles, will this directly
>   impact any of my testing devices while I'm in the process of the
>   iCloud development?

I'm sorry but I really don't know what to do here and any guidance on taking this forward would be really appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: **I've seen cover implementing iCloud into a new app rather than an app that already exists in the App Store and which already has an App ID and provisioning profiles**, then why do you have question **Do I have to create a new App ID**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to create new app id simply what you have to do is add new features to existed app id.

If you go to apple development portal--> login to your account there you will see.

Click on Certificates,identifiers & profiles--> Click on Identifiers--> Then Click on identifier to whom you want to add new feature  say "iCloud"

At the bottom you will see Edit button

[image]

Click on edit you would be taken to a new screen where you can add new feature iCloud to it.

Now here are few points that  you have to remember.

You would have to alter you all certificates for this identifier and then regenerate new ones. Remember all provisioning profiles,certificates need to be regenerated for this App Id.

I have done so many times further you can ask i will help you.

Comment: Thanks so much Husrat - that's really helpful and I really appreciate the screenshots and guidance on this. Just one quick question to follow up - I have to generate new certificates and profiles. Right now, I have a iOS Distribution Certificate and a Development AND Distribution Profile - I need to recreate all of those (by creating a new certificate)?

Comment: Yes exactly first add features and then alter you provisioning profiles etc for this particular app id.

Comment: Thanks Husrat and apologies for the late reply. Your approach worked perfectly and I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Wellcome Lavanya,its my real pleasure to share what i know